# iPad - Change all elements' text color on a view simultaneously

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface

Is there a way to have all the text of all the labels, buttons and title's change to a single color with a simple piece of code?

Such as looping through all 'elements' on a view or similar?

I need to be able to toggle the text color of my whole app with a single button. But can't seem to find an efficient way to alter all the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This certainly isn't one or two lines, but it does the trick and is generally what I use.

```
for(UIView *v in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        [(UILabel *)v setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    else if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        [(UITextView *)v setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    //etc...
}
```